# Русская кодировка в phpMyAdmin.

Tags: phpmyadmin, кодировка

Как сделать русскую кодировку в phpMyAdmin? Когда читаю из базы данных, то все русские символы заменяются вопросами. Сейчас стоит кодировка utf8_general_ci, но какую кодировку не ставлю, все равно знаки вопроса вместо русских символов. База данных работает не в веб-приложении, а для программ, расположенных на разных компьютерах. Что делать?

Comment: Сравнение cp1251_general_ci мне когдато помогло

Comment: Возможно проблема в том, что данные заливаются в БД в некой другой кодировке...

Answer (score 1):

Смотря как заливали данные в БД быть может в другой кодировке и тут сам бог велел исправить все на "вопросы".

Решение залить БД в кодировке WIN1251

Comment: А если кодировка базы UTF-8_general_ci, то если залить в кодировки UTF8, тогда все будет нормально?

Comment: Да бросать уже надо 1251.
ИМХО новые проекты лучше делать на UTF-8

Comment: Вот по суть windows-1251 не дает масштабируемости по тому что только русский язык поддерживает, да и к тому же не на столько больше места в БД жрет, при нынешних ресурсах серверов.